# In a max heap H of n elements, the top 2 powerk -1 elements are in the first k levels. How to prove this as false?

Tags: heap

Prove the above statement as `false`.

> n and k are positive integers such that 2 powerk -1<=n.

In a max heap of n elements, the top 2 powerk -1 elements are in the first k levels.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

> The top 2<sup>k-1</sup> elements are in the top `k` levels.

We can prove this by contradiction. Here is a max heap of 15 items.

```
         F
       /   \
     E       7
    / \     / \
   D   A   6   5
  / \ / \ / \ / \ 
  C B 9 8 4 3 2 1
```

This is a valid heap. Every item is smaller than its parent.

So let's assume your assertion is correct, that the top 2<sup>k-1</sup> elements are in the top `k` levels. So the top 4 (2<sup>3-1</sup>) elements should be in the top 3 levels. In this case, that would be F, E, D, and C. But C is in the 4th level. That contradicts the assertion.

Or do you mean that the top 2<sup>k</sup>-1 items must be in the top `k` levels? In that case, the top 3 (2<sup>2</sup>-1) must be in the top 2 levels. But again, the item D, which is the 3rd largest, is in the 3rd level. Again, that contradicts the assertion.